# Can't Display new page in existing UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I am new to objective-c and have been stumped with this problem for weeks now. So would greatly appreciate any help with this.

I am developing an i-phone app that has a tab view and one of the tabs is a UIWebView. Another tab provides a way to select what should be displayed in the UIWebView.

I can display the initial view in the UIWebView (in viewDidLoad) with:

```
[self.groupWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

That works perfectly well.

But when the user selects something on the table view it has to open a new page in the existing UIWebView.

So I have this:

```
-(void) displayGroup:(int)theGroup
{
    // Set our selves to the webviews delegate since we implement the delegate methods here
    self.groupWebView.delegate = self;

    // Load it to the webview

    NSString *html = @"<html><head><title>it worked...</title></head><body><a href=\"custom://THIS_IS_CUSTOM_LINK\">Click for custom link</a><br><a href=\"http://google.com\">it worked...</a></body></html>";
    [self.groupWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];

}
```

I call this and it runs but nothing happens on the web view.

the .h file looks like:

```
//  PBGroupViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PBGroupViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> 

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *groupWebView;
- (void) displayGroup:(int)theGroup;

@end
```

Any help on this would be very greatly appreciated... Thank you.

Comment: Verify that your webView not nil

Comment: The webView is displaying the initial page so I assume it is not nill. But I do not think this function displayGroup is actually connecting to the webView. I am new at this and missing something I think. Maybe the displayGroup function is supposed to have the webView as one of the parameters of the function? I do not know... But I think I am not connecting to the webView...

Answer (score 0):

Change your `displayGroup` function like this:

```
-(void) displayGroup:(int)theGroup
{
    // Set our selves to the webviews delegate since we implement the delegate methods here
    self.groupWebView.delegate = self;

    // Load it to the webview

    NSString *html = @"<html><head><title>it worked...</title></head><body><a href=\"custom://THIS_IS_CUSTOM_LINK\">Click for custom link</a><br><a href=\"http://google.com\">it worked...</a></body></html>";
    [self.groupWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
    [self.groupWebView stopLoading ];
    [self.groupWebView reload];
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't do anything at all. The webview just stays on the initial page. Nothing changes...

Answer (score 0):

when the user clicks on the table view is some url is generated....If yes then you should use didSelectRowAtIndexPath and in that you should load your webview..

Comment: It will be loading from a string of html text generated by the program, not a url. And currently the program is calling the displayGroup function and that is running at the right time but it does not display anything in the UIWebView. So we have to find out why the displayGroup function is not working....